# How to iterate through rows of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I have this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','New_addy','PHONE1','PHONE2','EMAIL'])

def QuestioningMech(df):
    for x in df:
        print(df[x])
```

So I am trying to iterate through the DataFrame, but this code iterates over columns. How do I iterate over rows instead?

Comment: That is not a CSV file. Please provide some sample data (make a fake dataset), and an expected result

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/5400385) if you're using Pandas.

Comment: If you want to iterate through a Pandas DataFrame, then say so. The CSV file format is a totally separate thing that has nothing to do with the code shown. I am removing that tag.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows` iterates rows. So,

```
def QuestioningMech(df):
    for row in df.iterrows():
        print(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
QuestioningMech(df)
```

This is not be the most efficient way to handle a dataframe, depending on what you plan to do with the data.